# Is it possible to control the formatting of the coordinate-output of CalculateGeometryAttributes (remove white space)?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro

I'm using:

- ArcGIS Pro 2.8
- [CalculateGeometryAttributes  Calculate Geometry
  Attributes (Data Management)](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/calculate-geometry-attributes.htm)
- arcpy.management.CalculateGeometryAttributes(in_features,
  geometry_property, {length_unit}, {area_unit},{coordinate_system}, {coordinate_format})

I have a field called `USNG_CODE`which I'm trying to field-calculate the geometry for, but I'm running into a field length issue. The tool outputs USNG notation *with* spaces (example: `15T WN 57013 97278`) but my output field is only 15 characters long and requires the coordinates be formatted without spaces (example: `15TWN5701397278`).

I've tried working with the python to .strip() the coordinate string before it's written as output, but I'm not sure how/where to accomplish this.

I'd like to do something like this (which doesn't work for obvious reasons):

```
import arcpy
x=arcpy.management.CalculateGeometryAttributes("AddressPoints", "USNG_CODE POINT_COORD_NOTATION", '', '', None, "USNG")
x.strip()
```

...clearly I'm not handling the variable correctly, but I'm not sure how else to approach this. Is it possible to control the formatting of the output of the CalculateGeometryAttributes tool?

Comment: Alternate question: is there a simple/other way to calculate USNG coordinates into a 15-character field in ArcGIS Pro?

Comment: `str.strip` only removes leading/trailing chars; you want `str.replace(' ','')`.

Comment: (Original poster)
A smart colleague pointed out a great work-around: for some reason the calculate geometry > MGRS format does not include the spaces that the USNG calculation has. So for now, I'm just using that.
Technically this doesn't answer my question as-posted above, but it's a great work-around.